# Testing repositories which do not extend any Spring Data Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4, spring-repositories

I am writing unit and integration tests for my app and I have a problem with testing repositories.

This is very simple repo for handling authorities:

```
public interface AuthorityRepository {
    Authority saveAuthority (Authority authority);

}
```

```
@Repository
public class AuthorityRepositoryImpl implements AuthorityRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired
    public AuthorityRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Authority saveAuthority(Authority authority) {
        entityManager.persist(authority);
        return authority;
    }
}
```

I have two questions regarding this code:

1. Is it wrong approach to not extend any Spring Data Repository interface? Besides not having to write all methods to communicate with database what are other advantages of using it?
2. How can I test this repository using minimum resources? `@DataJpaTest` does not work, because (from my understanding) it picks up repos that extend any Spring Data Repository. This works:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AuthorityRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private AuthorityRepository authorityRepository;
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void test () {
        Authority authority = new Authority();
        authority.setName("name");
        authority.setUsername("username");
        authorityRepository.saveAuthority(authority);
        assertNotNull(entityManager.find(Authority.class, 1));
    }
```

But `@SpringBootTest` is pretty slow as it creates whole application context and I would like to make these tests faster.
I am using H2 database both in main and test, which is declared in `application.properties` file.

Comment: 1) It's not wrong, but I don't see why you **wouldn't** use a proper repository 2) You shouldn't be testing a repository in the first place, since it contains no business logic

Comment: Thanks :) What if I have some advanced queries and I want to check if they return proper results and make sure they still do after I make changes to code?

Comment: Integration tests would be a better place for those. Besides, code changes don't usually break queries. Data changes do.

Comment: Have you tried using `DataJpaTest`? It should work as it will bootstrap a minimal test and configure JPA and optionally Spring Data JPA. Something like `@DataJpaTest(AuthorityRepositoryImpl.class)`. Should be possible.

Comment: Use `@SpringBootTest` or `@DataJpaTest` in integration tests only. Integrations tests are slow and they should be separated from unit tests. Unit tests should be run frequently unlike integration tests. Integration tests usually are run once before pull request/push to repo and on CI pipeline.

Comment: M. Deinum - unfortunately I could not find a way to tell @DataJpaTest that it should pick up my repo when creating context, BUT thanks to your suggestion I just tried `@Import(AuthorityRepositoryImpl.class)` and it worked :) Also it is faster, so that is step in right direction, thanks

Comment: @MaximMarkov I dont want to unit test repos, because that doesn't make much sense. I am aware these are integration tests, I just want to make them faster, because there is no need for whole application context when I want to test only specific part of my app.

Answer (score 1):

`@DataJpaTest` works when coupled with `@Import(repo.class)`. It looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest ()
@Import(AuthorityRepositoryImpl.class)
public class AuthorityRepositoryTest2 {

    @Autowired
    AuthorityRepository authorityRepository;
    @Autowired
    TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Authority authority = new Authority();
        authority.setUsername("name");
        authority.setUsername("username");
        authorityRepository.saveAuthority(authority);
        assertNotNull(testEntityManager.find(Authority.class, 1));
    }
```

I learned though, that if I do integration test I could aswell create whole application context and test all things I want reusing this one context, so later when I write more integration tests for other parts of my app I am going to end up using `@SpringBootTest` for all of these tests anyway.

Thanks for comments, helped me to understand integration tests better.